# c# конвертация кодировки

Tags: c#

Требуется программа которая будет текст из 1252 переводить в 1251.

```
   var bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(textBox1.Text);
   textBox2.Text = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(bytes);
```

Отлично справляется. Но хотелось бы без копи паста просто выбирать файл. Делаю по аналогии.

```
        string file_data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
        var bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(file_data);
        string file_data_in_1251 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(bytes);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path + "_1251", file_data_in_1251);
```

И получают на выходе файл с ?????.

Попытка добавить

```
 string file_data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
```

И

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path + "_1251", file_data_in_1251, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
```

Толку не дала. Чяднт?

```
yte[] allData = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
    string file_data_in_1251 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(allData);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path + "_1251", file_data_in_1251, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
```

Так часть файлов отрабатывает часть нет :(. При этом не рабочие файлы нормально конвертируются через изначальный вариант.

Последовательности байтов очень сильно отличаются от варианта получения из текста и из файла. Текст:

```
    [0] 32  byte
    [1] 60  byte
    [2] 32  byte
    [3] 116 byte
    [4] 97  byte
    [5] 103 byte
    [6] 32  byte
    [7] 107 byte
    [8] 32  byte
    [9] 61  byte
```

Файл:

```
    [0] 32  byte
    [1] 60  byte
    [2] 116 byte
    [3] 97  byte
    [4] 103 byte
    [5] 32  byte
    [6] 107 byte
    [7] 61  byte
    [8] 39  byte
    [9] 78  byte
```

Comment: Хорошо, а в переменной у вас нормальные данные появляются?

Comment: @iluxa1810 нет там уже вопросы ( смотрел через точку остановки ).

Comment: А вы уверены, что файл сохранен в кодировке, которую вы используете для чтения?

Comment: @iluxa1810 стандартная 1251 windows.

Comment: string file_data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)); А почему вы тут тогда читаете, как 1252?

Comment: @iluxa1810 я пробовал и с указанием кодировки и без. Бестолку.

Comment: А винда у вас на каком языке?

Comment: @iluxa1810 русский. 1251. Добавил выше код - с ним часть файлов отрабатываются корректно а часть не работает. При этом тоже содержимое файла корректно отрабатывает через первый код ( первые две строчки ).

Answer (score 0):

Один из этих вариантов отработает. Вариант 1 читаем побайтово:

```
byte[] allData = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
string file_data_in_1251 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(allData);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path + "_1251", file_data_in_1251, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
```

Вариант 2 читаем построчно суём в массив - объединяем массив в строку - получаем из строки байты - переводим в строку с другой кодировкой.

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
string line;
string lin2;
int counter = 0;

while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    counter++;
}
file.Close();

System.IO.StreamReader file2 = new System.IO.StreamReader(path);

string[] file_by_lines = new string[counter+5];

for(int i =0; i < counter; i++)
{
    lin2 = file2.ReadLine();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lin2))
    {
        file_by_lines[i] = lin2;
    }
}
file2.Close();

string file_by_line = string.Concat(file_by_lines);

var b = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(file_by_line);
string s = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetString(b);

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path + "_1251_variant1", s, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251));
```